# Add and remove THREE.Points from scene in three.r84

Tags: javascript, three.js

I recently switched from three.js revision 71 to revision 84.
When using the THREE.PointCloud it was very easy to update (adding and removing) points from the scene like this:

```
function updatePoints(newData) {

    geometry.dispose();
    geometry.vertices = [];

    geometry.vertices.push(...);

    scene.add(newPoints);
    render();
}
```

Now in revision 84 THREE.PointCloud is replaced by THREE.Points and this pattern doesn't work anymore and I'm clueless why this is. 
My actual code works perfectly fine in r71 but in r84 only some points get removed. The raycaster does not work on the points that should be removed neither can they be animated but they do not disappear from the scene.

I tried multiple things by adding `scene.remove(oldPoints);`and `geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;`to the function as well as adding different `setTimeout` before rendering and adding the points to the scene. None of this worked.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you,

k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already need to recreate the vertices, it's not that much more work to recreate the whole cloud:

```
geometry.dispose();
geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

geometry.vertices.push(...);

scene.remove(pointCloud);
pointCloud = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
scene.add(pointCloud);
```

https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/zwqvmP

Comment: Thank you Sphinxxx! This is great. You are right this works perfectly and isn't much more effort. Still it's unclear to me why this doesn't work anymore  but I'm totally fine doing it this way.